# Mean over a list by position in R

Tags: r

```
set.seed(0)
ESS <- list()

for (j in 1:100) {
    temp <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(1000),
                       v2 = rnorm(1000), 
                       v3 = rnorm(1000)); 
    ESS[[j]] <- temp
}
```

I want to reduce the list into a single dataframe, where each elements in this dataframe is the average of the 100 values stored in the list.

Comment: Not clear what you want. You want one hundred mean values of each of the 100 data frames across all the three columns of each data frame? The list has 100 data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already written 100 data.frames in ESS, ldply will return the colMeans of each data.frame and rbind them into a single output:

```
library(plyr)
ldply(ESS, colMeans)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you after average of averages?  If yes, try

```
df = data.frame(
  v1 = mean(as.numeric(lapply(ESS, function(x) mean(x$v1)))),
  v2 = mean(as.numeric(lapply(ESS, function(x) mean(x$v2)))),
  v3 = mean(as.numeric(lapply(ESS, function(x) mean(x$v3)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply/sapply` from `base R`

```
t(sapply(ESS, colMeans))
#                  v1            v2            v3
#  [1,] -0.0158295727 -2.478644e-02  0.0681427318
#  [2,]  0.0024859612  4.103752e-03  0.0197281287
#  [3,] -0.0020348399  4.206254e-02 -0.0488636326
#  [4,]  0.0594666004 -1.650206e-02 -0.0285346995
#  [5,] -0.0304168268  5.218406e-02  0.0146802682
#  [6,]  0.0349319791  3.032825e-03 -0.0278387255
#  [7,] -0.0237927055 -2.391049e-02  0.0304086913
#  [8,]  0.0125024040 -3.916709e-02  0.0089153103
#  [9,]  0.0061100088  2.059120e-02 -0.0262246088
# [10,] -0.0297768058  9.796194e-02 -0.0117578556
# [11,]  0.0061667120  1.629774e-02 -0.0108955127
# [12,]  0.0260390722 -5.002157e-02  0.0376300551
# [13,]  0.0190489482 -1.323166e-03 -0.0075387664
# [14,] -0.0205836198 -3.337794e-02 -0.0540212623
# [15,] -0.0187941477 -2.147293e-02 -0.0099970279
# [16,] -0.0398401942  5.897226e-02  0.0073399025
#    - - -
#    - - -
#[94,] -0.0039737458  2.082807e-02 -0.0315866491
# [95,]  0.0116898228 -2.924846e-02  0.0476551466
# [96,]  0.0331954808 -2.438589e-02  0.0006513433
# [97,]  0.0042186728  1.239381e-03  0.0102184203
# [98,] -0.0475462731  6.951947e-03  0.0315259709
# [99,] -0.0045903832 -5.146346e-03 -0.0426402874
#[100,] -0.0006757683 -4.334657e-02  0.0113538787
```

---

If this is based on position, then we can use `Reduce` from `base R`

```
newDat <- Reduce(`+`, ESS)/length(ESS)
```

Answer (score 1):

With purrr:

```
library(purrr)

ESS %>% map_df(~as.list(colSums(.x)))

#> # A tibble: 100 × 3
#>            v1         v2        v3
#>         <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1  -15.829573 -24.786443  68.14273
#> 2    2.485961   4.103752  19.72813
#> 3   -2.034840  42.062543 -48.86363
#> 4   59.466600 -16.502055 -28.53470
#> 5  -30.416827  52.184059  14.68027
#> 6   34.931979   3.032825 -27.83873
#> 7  -23.792706 -23.910489  30.40869
#> 8   12.502404 -39.167088   8.91531
#> 9    6.110009  20.591199 -26.22461
#> 10 -29.776806  97.961942 -11.75786
#> # ... with 90 more rows
```

or dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

ESS %>% bind_rows(.id = 'id') %>% 
    group_by(id = as.integer(id)) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum)

#> # A tibble: 100 × 4
#>       id         v1         v2        v3
#>    <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1      1 -15.829573 -24.786443  68.14273
#> 2      2   2.485961   4.103752  19.72813
#> 3      3  -2.034840  42.062543 -48.86363
#> 4      4  59.466600 -16.502055 -28.53470
#> 5      5 -30.416827  52.184059  14.68027
#> 6      6  34.931979   3.032825 -27.83873
#> 7      7 -23.792706 -23.910489  30.40869
#> 8      8  12.502404 -39.167088   8.91531
#> 9      9   6.110009  20.591199 -26.22461
#> 10    10 -29.776806  97.961942 -11.75786
#> # ... with 90 more rows
```